# Evaluating the definite integral of a trig function via complex analysis methods.

Tags: complex-analysis

> Show that
>   $$ \int_0^{\pi} \frac{1}{1 + \sin^2\theta} {\delta}\theta= \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}} $$

Normally if the limits of integration were from $0$ to $2\pi$ what I would, and have been taught to, do is covert the function to:

$$ \frac{1}{1 + \frac{1 - \cos(2\theta)}{2}}  = \frac{2}{3 - \cos(2\theta)} $$

and then considering the integral around the closed contour of the unit circle letting:

$z = e^{i\theta} $, $\cos(k\theta) = \frac{z^k + z^{-k}}{2} $, $\delta\theta = \frac{{\delta}z}{iz} $

Giving:

$$\int_{|z| = 1} \frac{4}{6 - z^2 - \frac{1}{z^2}} \frac{\delta{z}}{iz}$$

and finding the residues which lie within the closed contour

However as the limits of integration are from $0$ to $\pi$ not $2\pi$ I am unsure on what to do as I can't apply the method of residues in this case as I believe I would have an open half circle as a contour.

Comment: The answer of nikita2 is sufficient, however in an uneven case we point out that, to map $[0,\pi]$ to the unit circle, you could simply use $z=e^{i2\theta}$ instead of $z=e^{i\theta}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: It would be surprise but 
$$
\int_0^{\pi} \frac{1}{1 + \sin^2\theta} {\delta}\theta= \frac{1}{2} \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{1 + \sin^2\theta} {\delta}\theta.
$$

Comment: Well I'm awful once again. Thanks